# Magento new products widget shows new products twice

Tags: magento-1.9

I've added a widget to my Magento (1.9.x) homepage Page by adding this to the content source:

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="5" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

My new products show up, but they are displayed twice, in two separate HTML blocks.  After investigating I can see that it is using both these templates (once after the other):

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/main/template/catalog/product/new.phtml
app/design/frontend/mytheme/main/template/catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that, in the homepage Page, I already had some "Layout Update XML" defined in my Design for the Page.  Not sure why it hadn't showed up until after I added the widget code above to the Content, but I removed it and that fixed the issue.

In the end I actually found & used this http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/cms/widget-new-products-list.html which looks like a better way to do New Products on the homepage anyway (it allows better non-dev admin control).